# How to set a login page as landing page?

Tags: mediawiki

I have successfully Installed `MediaWiki` on my host. Can you please suggest me how do I set the landing page as login page? At present, it shows the main page.

Comment: Do your users need to be able to read the wiki without logging in?

Answer (score 0):

If MediaWiki uses Apache you should locate the .htaccess file and edit the following line:
`DirectoryIndex yourloginpage.php`

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I want to use the login page that comes with the mediawiki. How do I?